# Json desirialization using jackson with List of Abstract class Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I have a json structure like

```
{"myobj": { "ford" : [ {"color":"blue","ford_property":"A" } ], "audi": [ {"color":"red", "audi_property":"B"}, {"color":"black", "audi_property":"C"} ] } }
```

Class structure is

```
abstract class Car implements Serializable { 
    private String color;
    // getter setter here
}
class Ford extends Car { 
    private String fordProperty;
    // getter setter here
}
class Audi extends Car {
    private String audiProperty;
    // getter setter here
}
```

My Response class

```
class Response implements Serializable {
     private Map<String, List<Car>> myObj;
     // getter setters
}
```

Tried using `@JsonSubTypes` on `Car` class but that expects the `type` of `class` name as part of the object `{"color":"blue","ford_property":"A" }`.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if I get your problem, but I would suggest this anyway [Polymorphic JSON with jackson] (http://programmerbruce.blogspot.it/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html)

Comment: I tried that Polymorphic JSON with jackson the issue is that I dont have `type` as part of the class. But the `type` is the key of the list of the class.

so instead of `[{type:dog,name:foo}]` i have `{dog:[{name:foo}]}`

Comment: Ok, I would go with a custom deserializer if I were you. [Jackson – Custom Deserializer](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

You could probably accomplish this with change in your `Response` code and `SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE` + `DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` settings enabled

Here is demo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
    mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
    Response resp = mapper.readValue(json, Response.class);
}

public abstract static class Car implements Serializable {
    public String color;
}

public static class Ford extends Car {
    @JsonProperty("ford_property")
    public String fordProperty;
}

public static class Audi extends Car {
    @JsonProperty("audi_property")
    public String audiProperty;
}

@JsonRootName("myobj")
public static class Response implements Serializable {
    public List<Audi> audi;
    public List<Ford> ford;
}
```

**Option 2**

Don't change anything in your structure, no need for `WRAP_ROOT_VALUE`, but this will deserialize objects 2 times

```
public static class Response implements Serializable {
    private Map<String, List<Car>> myObj;

    @JsonAnySetter
    private void setter(String key, JsonNode value) {
        try {
            if (key.equals("ford")) {

                myObj.put(key, mapper.readValue(value.toString(), 
                                     new TypeReference<List<Ford>>() {}));
            } else if (key.equals("audi")){
                myObj.put(key,  mapper.readValue(value.toString(), 
                                   new TypeReference<List<Audi>>() {}));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 3**

Custom deserializer for `Response` almost the same as in `@JsonAnySetter` code from above, but can optimize it in deserializer.